# How do I send an email using javamail?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-mail

It looks like in http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javamail/javamail.html, the administrator sends email to another user(from email setting is default). But I actually have a submit form like this:

```
<form action="contact" method="post">
<p>Your email address: <input name="email"></p>
<p>Mail subject: <input name="subject"></p>
<p>Mail message: <textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit"><span class="message">${message}</span></p>
</form>
```

I actually want user to enter their email address, subject, and body(to email=my gmail is default).

How do I make change to sendMail method in http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javamail/javamail.html?

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the sendEmail method definition so the parameter "to" is renamed to "customerEmail". In the processRequest method, get the email the user entered using request.getParameter("email"), and pass that to the sendEmail method (instead of "to"). Then, in sendEmail, change this:

```
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
```

to

```
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(customerEmail));
InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS)};
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response first. But before writing code for sending email, the oracle asks me to get private info such as host, username, and password etc. Are these senders private info? If it is, I wouldn't be able to know them though!